# I don't get ring theory. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, soft-question

(All my rings are commutative with $1$.)

I've done two semester's worth of commutative algebra; in particular, a 3rd year undergraduate subject called "Rings, Modules and Fields" taught from the lecture notes (we mainly looked at ED's, PID's, and UFD's), and a masters level course called "Commutative and Multilinear Algebra" taught from Atiyah-Macdonald. After two semesters of this stuff, I still don't get it. Oh, I mean, I get some basic stuff. Irreducible elements in PID's induce maximal ideals. The number-theorist's concept of a gcd is generalized by the ring-theorist's intersection of ideals. Artinian implies noetherian, etc.

I understand some basic stuff.

But I still don't *get* it.

Honestly, what the hell are we even doing?

Okay, maybe that's a bit unfair.

Commutative algebra is huge; there's no one thing we're doing.

But the point remains that whenever I try to use commutative rings to do anything, it literally never works out.

For example, I'm a big fan of order theory and lattice theory, and I tend to think of elementary number theory in order-theoretic terms. So gcd is meet, lcm is join, etc. However, attempts to use lattices to understand commutative rings seem not to work so well for me. Here's an example. Someone asks a basic question about number theory. Maybe they want to prove something basic about coprimality. I think to myself: cool, I'll just formulate this in ring-theoretic terms and present a maximally general solution. A few hours later, I've cooked up no fewer than [three possible definitions of coprimality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728963/is-there-an-accepted-definition-of-coprimality-in-commutative-ring-theory). I have no idea which one to use, and now I'm stuck. Then, over the course of the next few weeks or months, I end up noticing that there's at least $3$ more possible definitions of coprimality. That's (at least) $6$ definitions. Six! Isn't this just one concept? In the end, I don't end up answering the person's question. I mainly just end up feeling frustrated.

> **Question.** I don't really get ring theory. Or at least, I can't use it do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a very odd question, and I'd say that most probably you're approaching the wrong way, and thus studying the wrong way, ring theory. You have several thousands books in the web and probably more in any decent university math's department's library. Go, dive into this and try to choose 3-4 that appeal to you because of the language, the approach, the educational point of view, etc.

Comment: Even with unity, commutativity and associativity, rings are pretty general mathematical objects, so of course there's lots of different generalizations and versions of concepts. The usefulness of ring theory in my experience almost always comes when there are extra assumptions in play making it less general. You seem to be confusing not knowing everything about ring theory with not getting ring theory. Surely some people believing that they "get" ring theory know less about it than you, just from glancing at your question, to the point your plea almost comes off as a humblebrag.

Comment: To be fair, it is almost impossible to write about yourself without sounding like a jerk.

Comment: After studying ring theory a long time, I've never really found any apgebraic structure formed by ideals to be useful. (However, I have been fascinated by that concept and have studied residuals E and multiplicative lattices.) I don't really think it important to be satisfied on that question for the purposes of ring theory.

Comment: Problem 2 is an interesting question which I would like to see answered. I know everything else you wrote probably makes you feel better, but really it is all just spoiling the post. Would you mind at least minimizing the tale of your travails and emphasize question 2? That would be great...

Comment: it just seems you have the wrong pov on commutative algebra. the correct pov uses algebraic geometry and  not order "theory" (are there any deep results you are using?). historically this is clear. also you seem to think too much about the elements of rings (as anyone can tell from what you say about different definitions of coprimality), while you should be thinking in terms of ideals. many statements (e.g. structure theorem for finite type modules over a pid) become more natural and more intutive when phrased in terms of ideals.

Comment: As for problem 2 just compare the fundamental theorem of arithmetic with unique factorization (phrased in terms of ideals) for Dedekind domains...

Comment: @rschwieb, regarding Problem 2, I'd love to oblige but I'm not quite sure what the question would be. What, specifically, do you want answered? Simply asking "how important is $(A \cap B)(A+B) = AB$" seems a little vague.

Comment: @goblin I was referring to `Problem 2. I don't to what extent ideals ought to behave like integers.`  Yes, a little broad, but I think this is definitely fair game, especially since ideals are advertised like this in so many contexts, and there are bound to be people who will ask "well, how great are the similarities?". Your particular thing about $(A\cap B)(A+B)$ is a good starting point for answers.

Comment: @goblin For what it's worth, [von Neumann's seminal work on continuous lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann#Lattice_theory) is an important work of order theory in geometry. This leads to von Neumann regular rings and other interesting algebras. He is more known for noncommutative geometry, though. Maybe if you chose some paths of study through his stuff you would gain insight that satisfies you.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the problem is that you need closer guidance by a supervisor in your attempts to initiate research. There is a somewhat romantic notion out there that one just starts studying mathematics and then naturally new ideas pop up and voila! one gets new results. In practice, however, doing research involves being supervised by a more experienced mathematician, and also being proposed research-level problem by a supervisor based on his experience suggesting that this direction could be fruitful.

There are obviously exceptional cases like Galois and Ramanujan but I wouldn't stake my career on it :-)

If I were to give a direct answer to your question "what am I doing wrong?" I would say "you are not seeking out an advisor to supervise your work".

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a perfectly reasonable candidate answer, although light on the mathematics of course. I'm hoping to walk away from this with some genuinely mathematical insights about how to use ring theory better.

Comment: In the influential book on ring theory from 1986 by Louis Rowen on page 72 you will find a description of the ultraproduct construction in ring-theoretic terms.  What happens, in a simplified case, is that you take the ring of functions on the reals, take a maximal ideal (*not* an ideal of functions vanishing at a real point), and take the quotient.  What you get is a proper ordered field extension of the reals, therefore containing infinitesimals and infinite numbers, where calculus a la Euler and Leibniz can be done in an intuitive way accessible to freshmen.  That's a useful application :-)