# If a number is divisible by prime factors of $x$ why is it divisible by $x$ as well?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example if I have a polynomial $p(x)$ that I want to show is divisible by 50 I can do that by showing that $p(x)$ is divisible by 2 and 25. Why is that? It strikes me as more intuitive that I would have to show that $p(x)=50k$ reduces to $1=k$ by dividing consecutively by 2, 5 and 5, however it suffices to show that $p(x)$ is divisible by those numbers. Why is this true?

Comment: Counterexample: $12$ divisible by $2,3,4$ but not by $2\cdot3\cdot4$.

Comment: For $12$ you need just $4,3$. I was referring to that in the question.

Comment: Then by the least fix the title of the question.

Comment: @ahra It is irrelevant what you meant if you write *other* thing. Barak is right: edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: $6$ is divisible by the prime factors of $9$, but not divisible by $9$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $ax+by=1$, that is, $(a,b)=1$, and $n=ka$, that is $a\mid n$, and $n=mb$, that is $b\mid n$, then
$$
\begin{align}
n
&=n(ax+by)\\
&=\overbrace{mb}^nax+\overbrace{ka}^nby\\
&=(mx+ky)ab
\end{align}
$$
that is, $ab\mid n$.

---

In the case in question,
$$
(-12)2+(1)25=1
$$
that is, $(2,25)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then: $$a \mid c, b \mid c \rightarrow ab \mid c.$$

This is [Definition 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728963/is-there-an-accepted-definition-of-coprimality-in-commutative-ring-theory) here. For example, if $3 \mid c$ and $10 \mid c$, then $30 \mid c$.

But, this doesn't work for $2$ and $10$, because they aren't coprime. For example, $2 \mid 10$ and $10 \mid 10$, but $\neg(20 \mid 10)$.

Comment: But $2,5$ would work? Is there any proof of this you could perhaps link to?

Comment: Here's a proof: this formulation of coprimality is just saying $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b) \mid c \rightarrow ab \mid c,$ by the universal property of LCM. In other words, it's just saying $ab \mid \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$. But this is equivalent to $ab = \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$. Now we use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ satisfies: $ab = \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$. So the statement of interest is equivalent to $$\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)= \mathrm{lcm}(a,b).$$ Hence by the cancellation law, we deduce $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) = 1$, which is the usual notion of coprimality.

Comment: @ahra, yes, $2$ and $5$ are distinct primes, so they're certainly coprime.